# Помогите разобраться с выпадающим меню

Tags: javascript, html, css

При наведении курсора на главный элемент div появляется выпадающее меню, но при попытке навести курсор на выпадающее меню оно исчезает... Еще, по задумке, отображаться черным цветом должна только область наведения курсора,а не все элементы div. И,неясно почему, div отображает список как единое целое при наведении курсора, а должно делиться на две части (INSTAGRAM и VK)

```js
document.getElementById("nav").onmouseover = function(event) {
    let target = event.target;
    if (target.className == "menu-item") {
    let s = target.getElementsByClassName ("submenu");
    closeMenu();
    s[0].style.display = "block";
    }
}

document.onmouseover = function (event) {
    let target = event.target;
    console.log(event.target);
    if (target.className!="menu-item" && target.className!="submenu") {
    closeMenu();
    }
}

function closeMenu() {
    let menu = document.getElementById("nav")
    let subm = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu")
    for (let i=0; i <  subm.length; i++) {
        subm[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.fullscreen-bg {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 45%;
}

    .overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

    .overlay2 {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
}
    .fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
    p {
     text-align: center;
     padding-bottom: 250px;
     color: white;
}

    .tga {
     color: white;
     font-family: Bradley Hand, cursive;
     font-style: italic;
     item-align: centerS;
}

    .menu-item {
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 150px 12px 150px 12px;
    background-color: gray;
    font-family: New courier;
}

    .menu-item > .submenu{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: gray;
    display: none;
}

    .menu-item:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    background: black;
}

    .menu-item > .submenu:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    background: black;
}

        .menu-item > .submenu2:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    background: black;
}

    .menu-item > .submenu2{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: gray;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style rel = "stylesheet" src="style.css"></style>

<body>


<div class="fullscreen-bg">
<div id="nav"; class="overlay2">
    <div class="overlay">

<p>

<strong class="tga">

Hey Everyone! My name is Artem!<br>
I'm a beginer for web-development and web-design. I'd appreciate if you choose me as a designer for you project (even if my salary is marginally low).<br>
Because every job I will make will be my advantage in the future! 

</strong>

</p>

<hr />

<p>

    Learnin' JS with conscience

</p>

</div>

    <div class="menu-item">
        Контакты
            <div class="submenu"><a href="instagram.com">INSTAGRAM</a>
                    <div class="submenu2"><a href="vk.com">VK</a></div>
    </div></div>

    <div class="menu-item">
        Мое портфолио
            <div class="submenu">В процессе ;)
                </div></div>

</div>
    
    <video loop="" muted="" autoplay="" poster="video/plane.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="https://sitehere.ru/examples/30.06.2015/video/plane.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video/plane.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>


</div>

</body>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Такое выпадающее меню проще и легче сделать без использования javascript, а используя :hover селектор в CSS. Вот пример - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

Если хочется с javascript, то вот минимальный вариант:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="menuBox">
    <div class="firstMenu">Contacts</div>
    <div class="dropdownElement">
        <a href="https://vk.com">VK</a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com">INSTAGRAM</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<style>
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    .menuBox{
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: #ffc99e;
        border-radius: 3px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .dropdownElement{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
    document.querySelector('.menuBox').addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
        document.querySelector('.dropdownElement').style.display = 'block';
    });
    document.querySelector('.menuBox').addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
        document.querySelector('.dropdownElement').style.display = 'none';
    });
</script>
</html>
```

На счет

> И,неясно почему, div отображает список как единое целое при наведении курсора, а должно делиться на две части

Не совсем понял вопрос, для того, чтобы разные элементы имели разные стили используйте разные классы.